# Call a pentaho spoon job or transformation from a rest or soap api

Tags: pentaho

We have a couple of jobs and transformations in pentaho that I'd like to call remotely from a script. Is there a way to call a job remotely? Can I also pass it variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho Data Integration does support remote execution. You're looking for a component called `Carte`.

Here's the docs:

[Carte User Documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation)